# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend' while running pytest

Tags: environment-variables, airflow, pytest, working-directory, pytest-fixtures

I am trying to test Airflow DAGs, so I created testing environment, Docker container with volume and connection to PostrgeSQL container.

When container runs, docker-entrypoint.sh installs all the packages, creates AIRFLOW_HOME temporary folder, links to the needed folders and files in volume and initializes airflow db.

After that current directory is changed to AIRFLOW_HOME and pytest is run as shown below:

```
pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

export AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES=False AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING=True AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_DEFAULT_CONNECTIONS=False

export AIRFLOW_HOME=$(mktemp -d -t airflow-XXXXXX)

mkdir -p $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins/backend

ln -s /workspace/pipelines/airflow/dags $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags

ln -s /workspace/pipelines/airflow/plugins/backend/__init__.py $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins/backend/__init__.py

ln -s /workspace/pipelines/airflow/plugins/backend/data_catalog $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins/backend/data_catalog

ln -s /workspace/backend/schema_catalog $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins/backend/schema_catalog

airflow db init

cd $AIRFLOW_HOME

pytest -s /workspace/pipelines/airflow/tests/test_dag.py
```

test_dag has some functions for db migration, data reloading to the tables, running the DAG and etc. Everything works perfectly fine.

Now I would like to put all the above preparation of airflow environment into the pytest fixture and leave only pytest running command in entrypoint script. I re-wrote everything into pytest fixture function as below:

```
@pytest.fixture
def airflow_instance(tmp_path_factory):
    # Set the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable to a temporary directory
    airflow_home = tmp_path_factory.mktemp('airflow')
    os.environ['AIRFLOW_HOME'] = str(airflow_home)

    # Create necessary directories and symbolic links
    backend_dir = airflow_home / 'plugins' / 'backend'
    backend_dir.mkdir(parents=True)

    dags_dir = airflow_home / 'dags'
    os.symlink('/workspace/pipelines/airflow/dags', str(dags_dir))

    init_py = backend_dir / '__init__.py'
    os.symlink('/workspace/pipelines/airflow/plugins/backend/__init__.py', str(init_py))

    data_catalog_dir = backend_dir / 'data_catalog'
    os.symlink('/workspace/pipelines/airflow/plugins/backend/data_catalog', str(data_catalog_dir))

    schema_catalog_dir = backend_dir / 'schema_catalog'
    os.symlink('/workspace/backend/schema_catalog', str(schema_catalog_dir))

    # Initialize Airflow database
    os.system('airflow db init')

    yield airflow_home
```

Everything seems similar to the previous shell script but test raises **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'**.

```
from backend.schema_catalog.model import citext
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'

/workspace/backend/migrations/versions/3081eed292ae_job_model.py:12: ModuleNotFoundError
```

I have tried to change directory into AIRFLOW_HOME inside pytest script.

```
os.chdir(airflow_instance)
```

So the functions run from that folder same as it was done through shell script.

However, I am still getting the same error.